# RoR: .create nils

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

(sorry for my english)
If i want to upload a new record with `:name` and `:date` params, thats what i found:

**Controller:**

```
  class ActorController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
      @actor = Actors.create
    end

    def create
      @actor = Actors.create(params[:actors])
      if @actor.save
        redirect_to actor_path, :notice => "Your actor was saved."
      else
        render "new"
      end
    end
  end
```

**Model: (actors.rb)**

```
  class Actors < ActiveRecord::Base 
    attr_accessible :birth, :name
  end
```

**And the View: (new.html.erb)**

```
<%= form_for(@actor) do |a| %>
  <%= a.text_field :name %>
  <%= a.text_field :birth %>
  <%= a.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**And my output in local server console is:**

```
Started PUT "/actor/40" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-27 13:38:15 +0100
Processing by ActorController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BKhrP1Rfkco7r05wPT758M3CHQXRP5l5jcul77oTLPw=", "actors"=>{"name"=>"Bunny", "birth"=>"19/21/21"}, "commit"=>"Update Actors", "id"=>"40"}
   (1.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "actors" ("birth", "created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["birth", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 27 Mar 2013 12:38:15 UTC +00:00], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 27 Mar 2013 12:38:15 UTC +00:00]]
   (197.8ms)  commit transaction
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/actor/40
Completed 302 Found in 209ms (ActiveRecord: 200.0ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please edit the following:

**1) Edit your Model:**

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base  # Class name should be Singular
  attr_accessible :birth, :name
end
```

**2) Edit your Controller:**

```
  class ActorsController < ApplicationController # Note Here the controller name should be plural without space
    def index
    end

    def new
      @actor = Actor.new  # In the new action, it should be classname.new not create
    end

    def create
      @actor = Actor.create(params[:actor]) # Here also the Actor class name should be singular
      if @actor.save
        redirect_to actor_path, :notice => "Your actor was saved."
      else
        render "new"
      end
    end
  end
```

`PS:`

**1)** In the View folder name should be Plural too, so your folder name is `app/view/actors`.
**2)** Change your controller name like `actors_controller`.
**3)** In your routes, it should be `resources :actors`.
**4)** You need to allign your code with correct indetation to find where you starting and where you ending. It's the good way to start coding. It will resolve your 50% problem to find where you doing wrong.

Comment: -1 end
but after when i fix it, it make another error:
uninitialized constant ActorController::Actor

Comment: See my Updated answer. In the controller it should be plural. So, `ActorsController::ApplicationController`

Comment: Expected /home/ben/blog/app/controllers/actor_controller.rb to define ActorController

Comment: Change the name of your controller to actors_controller.rb

Comment: ehhh,
i changed this and the resource routes too, but
NameError in ActorsController#new

uninitialized constant ActorsController::Actor

Comment: yeah... In the route `resources :actors`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27011/discussion-between-vinay-and-ben-c-taylor)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action, you have the wrong parameter name:

```
Actors.create(params[:movie]) should be Actors.create(params[:actors])
```

Comment: btw, you should name the classes in the singular form => Actor, not Actors

Answer (score 0):

Change your new actions code as:

```
@actor = Actors.new
```

and confirm that your model class is Actors
It may works.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of stuff going wrong here:

1. The controller name should be plural, and you will have to rename your file to be `actors_controller.rb`
2. The model name should be singular, also see that you change the name of the file to `actor.rb`
3. The new action should be `@actor = Actors.new` not `create`, #create is shorter version of #new and #save.
4. The params hash should be `params[:actor]`

> ```
> class ActorsController < ApplicationController   
>      def index   
>      end
>
>      def new
>         @actor = Actor.new   
>      end
>
>      def create
>         @actor = Actor.create(params[:actor])
>         if @actor.save
>             redirect_to actor_path, :notice => "Your actor was saved."
>         else
>             render "new"
>         end   
>      end 
>   end
> ```

Also change the model name in your Actor.rb and be sure that that's the name of the model.
Also in this case you should checkout your migrations.

```
  class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base 
    attr_accessible :birth, :name
  end
```

Comment: You have to change your file name also. it should be actors_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

`@actor = Actors.create` is wrong, because it assigns the @actor variable to a newly created Actors object. That's why you see `Processing by ActorController#update as HTML` in your output, because the object is already created and is trying to update it.

You should change this to `@actor = Actors.new`